# UNIQUE constraint on multiple columns with non-interchangeable values

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to put UNIQUE constraint on 2 columns, colA and colB. Once the constraint is set it will make sure that combination of values of colA and colB is UNIQUE,

It should also make sure that, for example,

For a row in a table, if colA value is 100 & colB value is 101, then colA value cannot be 101 and colB value cannot be 100 for any other row in that table.

Please suggest.

Regards,
Sachin

Comment: Is it acceptable to enforce (via `CHECK`) that `colA` is always less than `colB`?

Comment: No, its not the case that colA will always be less than colB. For any ID  in table, the values of colA and colB cannot be interchangeable. Please let me know if you need any further explanation. Though a solution with CHECK constraint should be acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

`Check` and `unique index`.

```
    create table uni(colA number, colB number);

    ALTER TABLE uni ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name  check( cola != colb);

    create unique index uni_idx on uni(  LEAST( cola , colb),GREATEST(cola , colb));

insert into uni values (100,101); (OK)
into uni values (100,102); (OK)
into uni values (101,100); (error)
into uni values (100,100); (error)
```

Comment: Yes you are right, I forget to remove `||` from index

Comment: How will I check the validity of this index in WHERE clause? I mean,                                  SELECT * FROM uni WHERE LEAST( cola , colb) = GREATEST(cola , colb) ? or some other codition like this?

Comment: But why do you want to check it? Do the insert and handle two exceptions (`ORA-02290,ORA-00001`)

Comment: Hi, due to a requirement, I have to check it and make an entry into a separate log table by forming a customized error message.

Comment: Handle exception and insert log. `begin  
   -- insert to table 
  commit;
exception
  when others then
    if sqlcode in (-2290, -1) then
       --insert to log table 
      commit;
    else
      raise;
    end if;
end;`

Comment: Thankyou, your idea is correct but I cannot use it in my implementation. I am generating some dynamic code (different code for different table) and hence can't use the EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS block in this case but have to use a USER defined exception. Somehow, I need a way to validate the condition given in Unique index.